# How to correctly install bumblebee 3.1 with nvidia-experimental-310

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Bumblebee doesn't work for me with the *experimental* NVidia driver. If I use NVidia *current*, everything is ok.

```
uname -a
Linux adrian-K55VM 3.8.2-030802-generic #201303031906 SMP Mon Mar 4 00:07:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

optirun glxspheres
[ 4799.789206] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 4799.789252] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

`more  /var/log/syslog | grep bumblebeed` [gives this output](http://wklej.org/id/977798/)

[my Bubmblebee config](http://wklej.org/id/977802/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and set Driver=nvidia and KernelDriver=nvidia-experimental-310 (instead of KernelDriver=nvidia). This is due to the ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates PPA changing the driver name.

Then `sudo service bumblebeed restart`.